# Hosted exchange 2010 email in office 365

Tags: exchange-2010, email-server, microsoft-office-365

A few of our employees (Org A) work for Org B. Org A (we) have Office 365 and Org B has hosted MS Exchange 2010. Our employees would like to access and also SEND emails from OWA with alias of Org B. This can be done using connected accounts. However, Org B refuses to support POP or IMAP with the Exchange.

How our users can connect to Org B email account to send and receive emails?

Is there a buffer medium that can be used to solve the case?

Thank you all!

Comment: Why don't OrgA users use Outlook Anywhere? What is a buffer medium? Why don't OrgA users log into OrgB using OWA?

Comment: Thank you! The idea is to send and receive both emails in O365. O365 gives our users lot of options with onedrive, sharepoint, etc. By this way, the users maintain one ecosystem. Buffer: Sorry about it. I tried sending and receiving using a container, it didn't work.

Comment: Also, how difficult it would be for OrgB to support IMAP or POP protocol? Is it too complicated to manage?

Comment: Well it's not terribly difficult but it may be that they don't want to deal with or manage POP and/or IMAP connections.

Comment: Thank you JOEQWERTY. Is there a workaround for the exchange connection in O365 without IMAP or POP other than using desktop version of Outlook?

Comment: Outlook Anywhere?

Comment: There's nothing much you can do on the Org A side, all the setup and configuration must be made from Org B, Ask their admins to provide you with a way to let your users connect to their Exchange, IMAP, POP3 and Outlook Anywhere are your available options, Outlook Anywhere is your best shot at this.

Comment: Thank you all for the valuable comments. I will see what I can do with Org B. Happy new year!